# ICMP redirect: how to test it with icmpush

Tags: redirection, icmp

I want to see how the routing table changes on a Linux system, when an ICMP redirect is received.
For that I use

```
icmpush -v red -sp current-gateway -gw new-gateway -dest google.com -c host -prot tcp my-eth1-ip-address
```

(which returns success), but the result of

```
route -n
```

remains the same.
Of course I have checked the the output of

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/accept_redirects
```

which is 1.
This is an Ubuntu 12 machine, with the last stable version of kernel, no firewall installed.

So the question: what could be going wrong?

Comment: It might be that Linux only accepts redirects that were sent in reply to another packet, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt), by default redirects are only accepted for those gateways that are already listed in the routing table.

```
secure_redirects - BOOLEAN
    Accept ICMP redirect messages only for gateways,
    listed in default gateway list.
    secure_redirects for the interface will be enabled if at least one of
    conf/{all,interface}/secure_redirects is set to TRUE,
    it will be disabled otherwise
    default TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

An assumption: the call of `icmpush` does not use the external interface `eth1`, but rather the localhost one `lo` so that the kernel does not recognize that it is a correct redirect from the gateway.
Besides, in very old versions of the linux kernel these routes were not displayed in the response of `route -n`. As I noted, the response of `route -nC` could be the correct way to include also the temporary redirect route.

@grawity, about accepting redirects that were sent in reply to another packet: did you read that somewhere? because I would be really interested in that.